# Counting Fermat witnesses and liars

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, primes, homework

We were asked to implement a program that calculates the number of Fermat witnesses and liars for odd numbers greater 1. This involves [Fermat’s little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Fermat’s little is used to identify whether a possible prime number is composite. It’ll find a number/numbers called Fermat witness then. The other numbers are Fermat liars unless Fermat’s little doesn’t find any witness. Then the number is *possibly* prime.

```
# coding=utf-8

"""Basic usage:
$ python fermat.py 7
(0, 0)
$ python fermat.py 9
(6, 2)
"""

import argparse


def main():
    """Prints out the results of fermat_witness_liar_count().
    fermat_witness_liar_count() takes a non-optional integer as an argument.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('possible_prime', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.possible_prime > 1 and args.possible_prime % 2 == 1:
        print(fermat_witness_liar_count(args.possible_prime))
    else:
        print("Please enter an odd integer > 1.")


def fermat_witness_liar_count(possible_prime):
    """Counts the amount of Fermat witnesses and liars
    for a number 1 <= test_num <= possible_prime.
    Basic usage:
    >>> fermat_witness_liar_count(3)
    (0, 0)
    >>> fermat_witness_liar_count(9)
    (6, 2)
    >>> fermat_witness_liar_count(31)
    (0, 0)
    >>> fermat_witness_liar_count(33)
    (28, 4)
    >>> fermat_witness_liar_count(437)
    (432, 4)
    """

    witness_count = 0
    liar_count = 0
    temp_liar_count = 0

    for test_num in range(1, possible_prime):
        if fermat_witness(test_num, possible_prime):
            witness_count += 1
        else:
            temp_liar_count += 1

    # When there are Fermat witnesses, all test_num’s that aren’t are Fermat liars
    if witness_count != 0:
        liar_count = temp_liar_count

    return witness_count, liar_count


def fermat_witness(test_num, possible_prime):
    """Basic usage:
    >>> fermat_witness(2, 3)
    False
    >>> fermat_witness(8, 9)
    False
    >>> fermat_witness(30, 31)
    False
    >>> fermat_witness(3, 33)
    True
    >>> fermat_witness(6, 437)
    True
    """

    if pow(test_num, possible_prime-1) % possible_prime != 1:
        # test_num is a Fermat witness, possible_prime composite
        return True

    # possible_prime may be prime
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be worth explaining the terms you are using : what is a liar ? what is a witness ?

Except for that, the code is well presented and well tested (so many thanks for that).

**Making code more simple in `fermat_witness`**

You could easily rewrite `fermat_witness`: `return pow(test_num, possible_prime-1) % possible_prime != 1`.

**Making code more simple in `fermat_witness_liar_count`**

You could also rewrite `fermat_witness_liar_count` with less variables because you can get rid of `liar_count` by writing :

```
if witness_count != 0:
    return witness_count, temp_liar_count
return 0, 0
```

You can also get rid of `temp_liar_count` by writing :

```
witness_count = 0
for test_num in range(1, possible_prime):
    if fermat_witness(test_num, possible_prime):
        witness_count += 1
if witness_count != 0:
    return witness_count, possible_prime - witness_count - 1
return 0, 0
```

Then, you can use the fact that non-zero integers are considered as true values and try to write a single `return`:

```
return witness_count, possible_prime - witness_count - 1 if witness_count else 0
```

Finally, if you want to count, you can use `sum` and simply write :

```
witness_count = sum(1 for test_num in range(1, possible_prime)
    if fermat_witness(test_num, possible_prime))
```

The whole function becomes :

```
witness_count = sum(1 for test_num in range(1, possible_prime)
    if fermat_witness(test_num, possible_prime))

# When there are Fermat witnesses, all test_nums that arent are Fermat liars
return witness_count, possible_prime - witness_count - 1 if witness_count else 0
```

**`pow` is a pow-erful builtin**

[pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) handles what you are trying to do in a more efficient way :

> if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more
>   efficiently than pow(x, y) % z)

`fermat_witness` becomes :

```
return pow(test_num, possible_prime-1, possible_prime) != 1
```

Then, I guess more mathematical optimisations could be performed but I haven't tried at all.

Comment: _Just_ added a brief description seconds before you answered. Thank you for the review.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is well structured, and the unit tests are a nice touch.

### `main()`

Error messages should be printed to `sys.stderr`, and failures should cause the program to exit with a non-zero status.  The `argparse` module does that; you should do it too, to be consistent.

I suggest inverting the condition.  It's better to write *validate, validate, …, validate, do it!*, since there are multiple ways to fail, and only one way to succeed.  (It doesn't make much difference in this case, but it's a good habit in general.)

```
if args.possible_prime <= 1 or args.possible_prime % 2 == 0:
    print("Please enter an odd integer > 1.", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
print(fermat_witness_liar_count(args.possible_prime))
```

### `fermat_witness_liar_count()`

It could be better expressed using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
count = Counter(fermat_witness(n, possible_prime) for n in range(1, possible_prime))
witness_count = count[True]
liar_count = count[False] if witness_count else 0
return witness_count, liar_count
```